# Cake php,validation message not showed

Tags: php, cakephp

i'm not able to catch and show validation errors into my CakePHP controller class.
I've this model:

```
public $validate = array(
    'username' => array(
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'required' => true,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
        'alphaNumeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('alphaNumeric'),
            'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
        'maxLength' => array(
            'rule' => array('maxLength', 50),
            'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),

    ));
```

and this is how i try to catch validation message into controller while save a new element into array:

```
public function add() {

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Admin->set($this->request->data);
        //$this->Admin->create();
        if ($this->Admin->validates()) {
            // it validated logic
            if ($this->Admin->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The admin has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The admin could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        } else {
            // didn't validate logic
            $errors = $this->Admin->validationErrors;
            debug($errors);
        }
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work. If i pass an empty field an  alert with a default message is showed into add.ctp page. If i insert a duplicate, no message is showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need

```
$this->Admin->set($this->request->data);
$this->Admin->validates(){}
```

because if you are using "save"

```
$this->Admin->save($this->request->data)
```

is validating already. That should do the job.

Comment: i added $this->Admin->set($this->request->data); to my answer. If you use "save" you don't need ->set() and ->validates().